# X-Frame-Options: DENY works only on backend port endpoints

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-security, x-frame-options, clickjacking

So since i'm working on spring security i've setted the headers.frameOptions to DENY, when i try this by putting my backend endpoint in an iframe which is **localhost:8080** [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA1t4.png) , everything is working perfectly fine, the thing is, when i put the frontend **localhost:3000** in iframe, nothing happens and the application is displayed in the iframe.
i'm thinking that the headers configuration i'm doing are applying only on APIs and not at the start of the application

[at the start of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL04H.png) as you can see there is no configuration : X-Frame-Options: DENY
[Here after i send an API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av1FB.png)

here is the function

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000)
            .includeSubDomains(true);

    http.headers()
            .contentTypeOptions();
    http.cors().and()
            .headers()
            .xssProtection()
            .and()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'")
            .and()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true).maxAgeInSeconds(31536000)
            .and()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("frame-ancestors 'none'")
            .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/swagger-ui.html", true).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AUTH_LIST).authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN') and hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue by configuring the frontend web.xml file by following [this](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/139277/how-to-configure-oneclicks-tomcat-server.html)
if u're using nginx as a server you can add :

**Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"**

if you're using any other server u can check [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options),

to conclude, if you're working on a full stack application you have to configure the server configuration file otherwise spring security won't prevent you from clickjacking.